# Visualforce Page won't update Custom Object records

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, dynamic-visualforce

I'm trying to create a custom Visualforce Page that will show related custom objects. I have it so that the user can press "Edit Details" and all the outputFields will turn into inputFields. The problem comes up with the user presses the "Save" button. Instead of updating the record, the pageBlock just refreshes to the old values. The idea of the page is to click on a record in a table and then a new pageBlock will open with the details of that record. I had some alerts to make sure that the record Id was being passed to the class properly but even with the id, the record won't update when the user tries to change the fields.

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="viewComponentControllerProjects">
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="projects">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(projs.size == 0, true, false)}">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Projects">       
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton value="New" immediate="true" action="{!ShowPopup}" rerender="projectPopup"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                No projects to display!
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(projs.size != 0, true, false)}" id="projs1234">
            <apex:pageBlock id="ProjectSelect" title="Projects">       
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="New Project" immediate="true" action="{!ShowPopup}" rerender="projectPopup"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projs}" var="p" styleClass="AccountTable">
                    <apex:column value="{!p.Name}" onclick="RerenderProjectDetails('{!p.Id}')"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!p.Description__c}" onclick="RerenderProjectDetails('{!p.Id}')"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="RerenderProjectDetails" rerender="ProjectInfo, Tasks, TaskDetail" immediate="true" action="{!init}">
        <apex:param name="selectedProj" assignTo="{!SelectedProjectId}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:outputPanel id="ProjectInfo">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(SelectedProjectId != '', true, false)}" id="ProjectInfo2">
            <apex:pageBlock id="MileStoneSelect" title="Project Details & Milestones">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton id="NewMileStone" value="New Milestone" immediate="true" action="{!ShowPopup}" rerender="milestonePopup" rendered="{!!editable}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton id="editProject" value="Edit Details" immediate="true" action="{!edit}" rerender="ProjectInfo, ProjectInfo2" rendered="{!!editable}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton id="saveProject" value="Save" immediate="true" action="{!saveProject}" rendered="{!editable}" rerender="ProjectInfo, pbsproj, projs1234, ProjectInfo2, projects"/>                      
                    <apex:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel" immediate="true" action="{!cancel}" rendered="{!editable}" rerender="ProjectInfo, pbsproj, projs1234, ProjectInfo2, projects"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsproj" title="Project Details" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Projects__c.FieldSets.projectInfo1}" var="field" >                            
                        <apex:inputField value="{!SelectedProject[field]}" rendered="{!editable}">
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedProject[field]}" styleclass="tableStyle" rendered="{!!editable}">
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Projects__c.FieldSets.projectInfo2}" var="field">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!SelectedProject[field]}" rendered="{!editable}">
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedProject[field]}" styleclass="tableStyle" rendered="{!!editable}">
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Milestones" columns="1">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(milestones.size == 0, true, false)}">
                        <span style="margin: 30px auto">No milestones to display!</span>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(milestones.size != 0, true, false)}">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!milestones}" var="m" styleClass="AccountTable">
                            <apex:column value="{!m.Name}" onclick="RerenderMilestoneDetails('{!m.Id}')"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!m.Description__c}" onclick="RerenderMilestoneDetails('{!m.Id}')"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!m.Status__c}" onclick="RerenderMilestoneDetails('{!m.Id}')"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>          
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="RerenderMilestoneDetails" rerender="Tasks, TaskDetail, ProjectInfo" immediate="true" action="{!initTasks}">
        <apex:param name="selectedMilestone" assignTo="{!SelectedMilestoneId}" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
    ...
```

Apex Class

```
public class viewComponentControllerProjects {

Public Projects__c proj {get;set;}

public String SelectedProjectId {get;set;}
public String SelectedMilestoneId {get;set;}
public String SelectedTaskId {get;set;}
Public Integer size {get;set;}
Public Integer noOfRecords {get;set;}

public List<Projects__c> projs {get; set;}
public List<Milestone__c> milestones {get;set;}
public List<task> alltasks {get;set;}
public Task selectedTask {get;set;}
public Projects__c SelectedProject {get;set;}
public Milestone__c SelectedMilestone {get;set;}

public Map<string, string> taskFieldSetLabels{get;set;}
public List<String> MyFieldListTasks {get;set;}
public Map<string, string> projectFieldSetLabels{get;set;}
public List<String> MyFieldListProj {get;set;}
public Map<string, string> milestoneFieldSetLabels{get;set;}
public List<String> MyFieldListMile {get;set;}

public Projects__c newProject {get;set;}
public Milestone__c newMilestone {get;set;}
public Task newTask {get;set;}

public boolean displayPopup {get;set;}

public boolean editable {get; set;}
public boolean editableMilestone {get; set;}
public boolean editableTask {get;set;}

public String editedProject {get;set;}
public String editedMilestone {get;set;}
public String toDeleteTask {get;set;}

public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller{
    get{
        if(controller == null){
            controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name, OwnerId, Description__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Implemented_Date__c, Priority__c, Requested_Date__c, Requested_Due_Date__c, Status__c, Hours_Spent__c FROM Projects__c]));
            controller.setPageSize(size);
            noOfRecords = controller.getResultSize();
        }
        return controller;
    }
    set;
}



public PageReference init(){
    if(SelectedProjectId != ''){
        String milestoneSOQL = 'SELECT ID, Name, Date_Completed__c, Description__c, Estimated_Hours__c, Labels__c, Pivotal_Tracker_ID__c, Project__c, Sprint__c, Status__c FROM Milestone__c WHERE Project__c =: SelectedProjectId';
        milestones = database.query(milestoneSOQL);
        SelectedProject = database.query('SELECT Name, OwnerId, Description__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Implemented_Date__c, Priority__c, Requested_Date__c, Requested_Due_Date__c, Status__c, Hours_Spent__c FROM Projects__c WHERE Id =: SelectedProjectId');
    }
    SelectedMilestoneId='';
    SelectedTaskId='';
    return null;
}


public PageReference initTasks(){
    if(SelectedMilestoneId != ''){
        String tasksSOQL = 'SELECT ID, ActivityDate, OwnerId, WhoId, WhatId, Priority, Status, Subject, Hours_Spent__c, Requested_By__c, Assigned_by__c, Comments_Trunc__c  FROM Task WHERE WhatID =: SelectedMilestoneId';
        alltasks = database.query(tasksSOQL);
        SelectedMilestone = database.query('SELECT ID, Name, Date_Completed__c, Description__c, Estimated_Hours__c, Labels__c, Pivotal_Tracker_ID__c, Project__c, Sprint__c, Status__c FROM Milestone__c WHERE Id =: SelectedMilestoneId');
    }
    SelectedTaskId='';
    return null;
}

public PageReference initTaskDetail(){
    if(SelectedTaskId != ''){
        String singleTaskSOQL = 'SELECT ID, ActivityDate, OwnerId, Description, WhoId, WhatId, Priority, Status, Subject, Hours_Spent__c, Requested_By__c, Assigned_by__c, Comments_Trunc__c, Time_Started__c, Time_Spent__c, Time_Completed__c FROM Task WHERE ID =: SelectedTaskId';
        selectedTask = database.query(singleTaskSOQL);
    }
    return null;
}

public viewComponentControllerProjects(){
    editable = false;
    editableMilestone = false;
    editableTask = false;

    projs = database.query('SELECT ID, Name, Description__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Implemented_Date__c, Priority__c, Requested_Date__c, Requested_Due_Date__c, Status__c, Hours_Spent__c FROM Projects__c');

    SelectedProjectId='';
    SelectedMilestoneId='';
    SelectedTaskId='';

    newProject = new Projects__c();
    newMilestone = new Milestone__c();
    newTask = new Task();

    toDeleteTask = '';
    init();
}

...

public void saveProject(){
    upsert SelectedProject;
    projs = database.query('SELECT ID, Name, Description__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Implemented_Date__c, Priority__c, Requested_Date__c, Requested_Due_Date__c, Status__c, Hours_Spent__c FROM Projects__c');
    editable = false;
}
```

Comment: You should never have a `save` button with `immediate="true"`.

Comment: as that will bypass the data from being sent in the ajax call thus not updating your fields... :)

Comment: I didn't even notice that I had copied and pasted it in. That solved my problem! Thanks!